# На сайте нужно сделать страницу со статьями

Tags: wordpress

друзья. Новичок в WordPress, поэтому не судите строго. На сайте имеется страница "Новости", на которой выводятся все записи. Возникла необходимость создать страницу "Статьи". Как в таком случае, разделить записи по страницам? Т.е. я хочу, чтобы одни записи отображались на странице "Новости", а другие на странице "Статьи".  Возможно ли сделать подобное? Если да, то правильно ли это?

Comment: Нужно создать новый кастомный тип https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/#custom-post-types

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать 2 категории "Новости" и "Статьи" и все записи распределить как тебе удобно

Comment: А если у записей имеется уже 3 категории, и я не хотел бы добавлять категорию "Статьи". Возможна ли какая-то другая альтернатива? Еще раз прошу прощения, возможно мои слова кажутся бредом, но сталкиваюсь с этим впервые, хотелось бы разобраться(

Comment: Вы можете зарегистрировать свою такскономию (это тоже самое что и категории/метки) и тогда можно будет создавать внутри термины

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Направили меня в нужном направлении